# Store string data in variable then export batched variable to JSON file at the end of the day with double quotes instead of single

Tags: python, json

Have this code running on a Raspberry Pi. I had this working properly by appending data to the JSON file, but the program would crash as the file size increased. I believe that was because the read/write speed to SD card was too slow. Saving to memory and dumping at the end of the day has been working great, but the JSON file is not proper. I need these files to have double quotes instead of singles, be proper JSON. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
def program():
    import json
    global count, pulse_start, pulse_end, pulse_duration, jsondata

    ts = time.time()
    hourofday = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H%M')
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    to = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    do = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    TRIG = 23
    ECHO = 24

    GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    time.sleep(2.5)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

    time.sleep(0.00001)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:

        pulse_start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

    distance = pulse_duration * 17150
    distance = round(distance, 2)

    GPIO.cleanup

    #for testing
    distance = 1
    if distance < 150:

        count = count + 0.5
        counter = str({"datetime": st, "time": to, "date": do, "Count": "0.5"})
        jsonlist = [jsondata, ",",  counter]
        jsondata = ''.join(jsonlist)
        print("Record added memory. There have been ", count, "customers so far today.")

    if hourofday == "2359":
        import json

        with open('counter-' + do + '.json', 'a') as json_file:
            jsonlist = ["[", jsondata, "]"]
            jsondata = ''.join(jsonlist)
            json_file.write(jsondata)
        print("File counter-", do, ".json created and saved.")
        time.sleep(60)
        count = 0
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        fulldate = now.date()
        jsondata = str({"index": {"_index": "customer-%s" % fulldate, "_type": "json_file"}})


count = 0
flag = True
now = datetime.datetime.now()
fulldate = now.date()
jsondata = str({"index": {"_index": "customer-%s" % fulldate, "_type": "json_file"}})

while flag:

    program()
```

I am getting output in file as:

```
[{'index': {'_index': 'customer-2017-12-19', '_type': 'json_file'}},{'date': '12-19-2017', 'Count': '0.5', 'time': '16:34:55', 'datetime': '12-19-2017 16:34:55'},{'date': '12-19-2017', 'Count': '0.5', 'time': '16:34:57', 'datetime': '12-19-2017 16:34:57'},{'date': '12-19-2017', 'Count': '0.5', 'time': '16:35:00', 'datetime': '12-19-2017 16:35:00'}]
```

Because this is JSON, I need all the single quotes to be double quotes for this to work. I am trying to do this all in one script without having to have a script to convert this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json.dumps(data)` and `json.loads(dump_data)` that will convert your single quotes to double quotes.

For converting a string:

```
import json

str1 = "{'index': {'_index': 'customer-2017-12-19', '_type': 'json_file'}}"

str2 = str1.replace("'", "\"")

data = json.dumps(str2)
json_data = json.loads(data)

print(json_data)
```

Outputs:

```
{"index": {"_index": "customer-2017-12-19", "_type": "json_file"}}
```

For converting a dictionary:

```
import json

dict1 = {'index': {'_index': 'customer-2017-12-19', '_type': 'json_file'}}

data = json.dumps(dict1)

print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
{"index": {"_index": "customer-2017-12-19", "_type": "json_file"}}
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it simply adds a double quote at the beginning and end of the entire output, leaving the single quotes in between. By the end of day, there are several hundred records in the variable to dump.

Comment: Thanks! That was a simple fix! Been bashing my head on the keyboard for days... added: jsondata = jsondata.replace("'", "\"") to the following:   with open('counter-' + do + '.json', 'a') as json_file:
   jsonlist = ["[", jsondata, "]"]
   jsondata = ''.join(jsonlist)
   jsondata = jsondata.replace("'", "\"")
   json_file.write(jsondata)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chemical for giving me a clean and simple fix to this code. Here is the fix, working code, and output. 
added: 
jsondata = jsondata.replace("'", "\"")

to with open section making the following:

```
with open('counter-' + do + '.json', 'a') as json_file:
    jsonlist = ["[", jsondata, "]"]
    jsondata = ''.join(jsonlist)
    jsondata = jsondata.replace("'", "\"")
    json_file.write(jsondata)
```

Complete fixed code as:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
def program():
    import json
    global count, pulse_start, pulse_end, pulse_duration, jsondata

    ts = time.time()
    hourofday = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H%M')
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    to = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    do = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    TRIG = 23
    ECHO = 24

    GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    time.sleep(2.5)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

    time.sleep(0.00001)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:

        pulse_start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

    distance = pulse_duration * 17150
    distance = round(distance, 2)

    GPIO.cleanup

    #for testing purpose
    #distance = 1

    if distance < 150:

        count = count + 0.5
        counter = str({"datetime": st, "time": to, "date": do, "Count": "0.5"})
        jsonlist = [jsondata, ",",  counter]
        jsondata = ''.join(jsonlist)
        print(jsondata)
        print("Record added memory. There have been ", count, "customers so far today.")

    if hourofday == "2040":
        import json

        with open('counter-' + do + '.json', 'a') as json_file:
            jsonlist = ["[", jsondata, "]"]
            jsondata = ''.join(jsonlist)
            jsondata = jsondata.replace("'", "\"")
            json_file.write(jsondata)

        print("JSON File created and saved.")
        time.sleep(60)
        count = 0
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        fulldate = now.date()
        jsondata = str({"index": {"_index": "customer-%s" % fulldate, "_type": "json_file"}})


count = 0
flag = True
now = datetime.datetime.now()
fulldate = now.date()
jsondata = str({"index": {"_index": "customer-%s" % fulldate, "_type": 
"json_file"}})

while flag:

    program()
```

Giving propper JSON in file as

[{"index": {"_index": "customer-2017-12-19", "_type": "json_file"}},{"time": "20:32:38", "date": "12-19-2017", "datetime": "12-19-2017 20:32:38", "Count": "0.5"},{"time": "20:32:40", "date": "12-19-2017", "datetime": "12-19-2017 20:32:40", "Count": "0.5"}]

Thanks again chemical!